# GetData put string in android EditText

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to put a URL received from Application B in to my application, in a EditText.
But im receiving null

Here is my code where im trying to get the intent:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mStreamUrl = intent.getDataString();
    FinalurlPrimit.setText(mStreamUrl);
```

layout:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_torrent_url"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bTorrentUrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:hint="@string/Text_magnet_sau_torrent_url"
        android:text="@+id/FinalurlPrimit"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

How can achieve this?
Thank you

edit

Log:

```
02-28 16:54:09.900 5698-5698/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming, PID: 5698
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.TorrentPlayer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.TorrentPlayer.onCreate(TorrentPlayer.java:48)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

02-28 16:54:11.988 5698-5698/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5698 SIG: 9

If you delete `android:text="@+id/FinalurlPrimit"`. everything work fine.

But I want the URL received, to appear in EditText

I do not have access to application B, and information from application B receive correct. Just can not display in EditText

Comment: Please include more detail for where the intent comes from and what you expect to receive. Also, your layout isn't necessary for this question

Comment: Use `Toast` to check whether `mStreamUrl` contains any values

Comment: mStreamUrl is not null, has received information from application B, the problem is somewhere in the introduction EditText

Comment: The information received from the application B, appear in EditText

Answer (score 0):

FirstActivity

```
String yourURL ="http://stackoverflow.com/";   
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("URL",yourURL);
startActivity(i);
```

SecondActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    String value = extras.getString("URL");
    FinalurlPrimit.setText(value);
}
```

Comment: I do not have access to application B, and information from application B receive correct. Just can not display in EditText

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the question is badly formulated. Do you verify the ID that associates the EditText? Because it seems that the EditText is null ...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `android:text="@+id/FinalurlPrimit"`. I don't think you need it. Between, `android: text` used to display the `text` you want it to show on `EditText` when there are no input on it. No `id` is required.

In `OnCreate` method, make sure you initialize the `EditText` as below

```
FinalurlPrimit= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bTorrentUrl);
```

Comment: I wish that, in ediText to appear that we have received information

Comment: show this  mStreamUrl = intent.getDataString(); in editText.

Comment: You want mStreamUrl display on EditText ?

Comment: yes ,url that we have received to appear in EditText

Comment: have you checked whether the `mStreamUrl` contains url ? If received, it was impossible  display nothing on EditText.

Comment: And make sure you decleare the **correct id** for `editText`